# Search and replace in UNIX

Tags: perl, shell, unix, sed, replace

How would i replace a string in a file such that the string to be replaced is always succeeded by some string.

eg: If i want to replace ABC with 123 as below,

**INPUT**

```
ABC
ABCXYZ
ABCDHD
ABC
CDE
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ABC
123XYZ
123DHD
ABC
CDE
```

i tried using sed but with no success.

Comment: sed -i '/ABC./s/ABC/123/g' <file> - how abt this ?

Comment: thanks to all. wanted to accept all, but can accept only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/ABC\(.+\)$/123\1/g' myFile.txt
```

`ABC`, match the literal ABC!

`\(.+\)` match at least 1 other character capture it in group 1

`123\1` replace the hole thing with 123 followed by what is captured in group 1

Comment: Some implementations of `sed` does not support the `+` as *one-or-more* of the previous group, however in this case there is no need for it. `sed -i 's/ABC\(.\)$/123\1/g' myFile.txt`, will work just as well.

Comment: @Chen, no it won't: you need to remove the `$` anchor, or else you're limiting the following text to exactly 1 char.

Answer (score 6):

Without capture using look-ahead:

```
s/ABC(?=\S)/123/;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/^ABC(.+)$/123$1/g' file.txt
```

This will however replace whitespace too. If you do not want that, instead of `.+` you can use `\S+`.

The `-i.bak` option will save a backup of `file.txt` in `file.txt.bak`, in case you bungled the replace.

Answer (score 1):

this one worked for me:

```
$ sed   -r  s/ABC\(.+\)/123\\1/g <file>
ABC
123XYZ
123DHD
ABC
CDE
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprised that no-one has used `\B`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  s/ABC\B/123/;
  print;
}

__DATA__
ABC
ABCXYZ
ABCDHD
ABC
CDE
```